# zsh - grab command history entry from a shell script

Tags: zsh

This is a zsh specific script, I'll worry about bash later (i.e. never).

Here's what I got so far.

```
#!/home/slu/.zsh/bin/zsh

# This is a shellscript generator that converts a history entry to a script
set -e

if [[ $2 =~ [0-9]+ ]]
then
    cmd= !$2
    echo "first arg is $1 and command is $cmd"
else 
    echo "Invalid 2nd arg"
    exit 1
fi
```

This obviously does not work as it looks for the command `!33` when I pass it `33` as the 2nd arg.

**In other words,** what is the zsh equivalent of bash's `history -p`?

How to get the script to expand it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is `fc -l $2 $2`

Full script kept updated [here](https://gist.github.com/unphased/5272286)